# $_get and include php

Tags: php, get, include

```
if (isset($_GET["nav"])) {
    if (!empty($_GET)) {
        $linkn = $_GET['nav'];
        if ($linkn == "nav1") {
            include("nav1.php");
        }
        if ($linkn == "nav2") {
            include("nav2.php");
        }
    } 
    else {
        include("nav1.php");
    }
}
```

I can't seem to get to nav2.php any idea?
sorry i been in a hurry while constructing it. what happens here this is in my index.php right navigation, i have separated php for my navigation which is nav1, nav2,. but i can't seem to change through my navigation, i have this code and i know there's something missing.

Comment: What's your question exactly?

Comment: Have you confirmed what is stored in `$_GET['nav']`? `var_dump` for us.

Comment: What is the value of `$linkn`?

Comment: you need to do `if(!empty($_GET['nav'])) {{`

Comment: Why are you not using `else if ($linkn == 'nav2')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$include = $_GET;
//Allowed navigations
$allowed = array('nav1', 'nav2');

//var must exist, have value and exist in allowed array
if (isset($_GET["nav"]) && !empty($_GET) && in_array($include, $allowed)){ 
  include($include.'.php');      
} else {
  include('nav1.php');
}
```

Comment: Note: the allowed array makes sure people cannot retreive any other files then the names in the array (url injection)

Comment: thanks, cool,..you can see through the code..